# Is there a complete Star Trek corpus available?

Tags: star-trek

I'd like to know if there is such a thing as a Star Trek corpus somewhere online. Has one ever been compiled?

By corpus I include the following:

1. The series episodes script.
2. The movies script

as text whatever the format (I can extract it).

Comment: I wouldn't mind knowing the answer to this one myself.  Unfortunately, questions asking for third-party resources or recommendations are considered off-topic on this (and most other) Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It would improve your question if you cited what you've looked at (if at all), so that we can reduce our search parameters.